# Cannot convert a string of integers to integers in C++

Tags: c++, atoi

I am currently at hand have a function at hand within a class, User::User(string id, string ratings).
I am attempting to currently store the string "1 5 5 3 0 -5 0 5" (which is the parameter for ratings, id is already dealt with) into a vector which cannot be changed called vector(int) <--integers ratings as a vector of 8 integers seen in the string. What is the best way to iterate through this string and store the individual values(negatives included)?

Comment: Check out `std::stringstream`.

Comment: define "best"... easy to reason about correctness? extended error handling? fast?

Comment: Best meaning that it will most efficiently place (in this case) 8 different values in an int vector from that stream, and will also recognize the spaces should not be converted to integers, and that negatives will cause the index in the vector to be a negative version of the next index in the string.

Comment: "and will also [...]" - that's just a basic requirement. so you want efficiency? (are you sure? I doubt you need it.) update you question.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and your question will be much easier to answer. We are not here to solve problems but to answer questions.

Comment: @SamAnoff Don't edit your questions like that.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream is("1 5 5 3 0 -5 0 5");
    std::vector<int> v;

    int n;
    while (is >> n)
        v.push_back(n);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        std::cout << v[i] << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem is a canonical use-case for [stream iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>


int main()
{
  std::istringstream iss{ "1 5 5 3 0 -5 -5" };
  std::vector< int > v;

  std::copy( std::istream_iterator< int >{ iss },
             std::istream_iterator< int >{},
             std::back_inserter( v ) );

  std::copy( std::begin( v ),
             std::end( v ),
             std::ostream_iterator< int >( std::cout, " " ) );
}
```